# SQL Join 2 Tables and leave null when not found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 Tables

[Countries]

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Japan |
| 2 | Egypt |
| 3 | France |
| 4 | England |
| 5 | Canada |

[VisitedCountries]

| UserID | CountryID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 |

I'd like to have a list of all the items in the [Countries] Table + 1 additional column with the UserID as the WHERE statement.
Like so :

[ExpectedResult] (WHERE UserID = 1)

| UID | CID | CName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | 1 | Japan |
| 1 | 2 | Egypt |
| 1 | 3 | France |
| Null | 4 | England |
| 1 | 5 | Canada |

I tried multiple different JOIN statements, but i still only get the lines where UID is not null only :

[WRONGResult] (WHERE UserID = 1)

| UID | CID | CName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Egypt |
| 1 | 3 | France |
| 1 | 5 | Canada |

```
SELECT c.*, vc.UID   
FROM [Countries] AS c 
JOIN [VisitedCountries] AS vc ON vc.CID = c.ID   
WHERE vc.UID = '1'
```

UNION ALL did not work either, it just returns 2 tables as a list, not joined.

Care to help or point me to the right documentation / direction?

Comment: Don't put answers in the question please - especially when people have actually provided answers below. You can thank them by "accepting" an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the condition on left joined table column from WHERE into ON clause of LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT c.*, vc.UID   
FROM [Countries] AS c 
LEFT JOIN [VisitedCountries] AS vc ON vc.CID = c.ID AND vc.UID = '1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to *outer join* your tables and note the conditions are part of the joining criteria, not a filtering criteria as you still require *all* rows:

```
select v.UserId, c.Id, c.Name 
from countries c
left join visitedcountries v on v.CountryId = c.Id and v.UserId = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd1717/5)

**Your Query**:

```
SELECT c.*, vc.UserID   
FROM Countries AS c 
JOIN VisitedCountries AS vc ON vc.CountryID = c.ID   
WHERE vc.UserID = '1'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd1717/5/0)**:

```
| ID |   Name | UserID |
|----|--------|--------|
|  2 |  Egypt |      1 |
|  3 | France |      1 |
|  5 | Canada |      1 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT c.*, vc.UserID   
FROM Countries AS c 
LEFT JOIN VisitedCountries AS vc ON vc.CountryID = c.ID AND  vc.UserID = '1'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd1717/5/1)**:

```
| ID |    Name | UserID |
|----|---------|--------|
|  2 |   Egypt |      1 |
|  3 |  France |      1 |
|  5 |  Canada |      1 |
|  1 |   Japan | (null) |
|  4 | England | (null) |
```

Comment: @DaleK because it was not specified `SQL Server` when I provide my answer... (and it's conventional SQL, so should run fine on SQL-serv too)